# How to add a command-line's window on software-center?

Tags: apt, software-center

I hate not seeing the command line on the software-center, and if I want to see it, I have only the console-system to install the software.

Installing a software without the name of the software is near to impossible, and with the "aptitude --full-resolver" command, it is a little boring...

Is possible to implement a command-line window in the software-center, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the package name to install it manually, you can find it above the reviews. The command line is always `sudo apt install <packages>`.
If you want to search a package without opening Ubuntu Software, you can use `apt`:

```
$ apt search firefox
firefox/artful-updates,artful-security,now 57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.17.10.5 amd64 [installed]
  Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla

firefox-dbg/artful-updates,artful-security 57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.17.10.5 amd64
  Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla - debug symbols

firefox-dev/artful-updates,artful-security 57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.17.10.5 amd64
  Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla - development files

[...]
```

Then, you can install the packages with `apt`, `apt-get` or `aptitude`. Also, `synaptic` has a handy interface.